# Unit test Struts

Tags: java, unit-testing, struts

I have the following Struts Action:

```
    public ActionForward addSomething(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    SomeForm sForm = (SomeForm) form;        
    Test t = testForm.toTest();

    if (tDao.checkExistsTest(t.getTest())) {            
        return mapping.findForward("failure");          
    } else {
        t.setType(new TestType(tess));
        t.setPassword(testForm.getPassword());

        tDao.add(t);

        return mapping.findForward("success");
    }        
}
```

I did the following code to test the *testAddSomethingSuccess* method:

```
    @Test
public void testAddSomethingSuccess() throws Exception {
    form.setTest("LOL");
    form.setTestName("lol");
    form.setPassword("12345");

    ActionForward forward = action.addSomething(mapping, form, request, response);

    assertEquals(tDao.getList().get(0).getTest(), "LOL");
    assertEquals(tDao.getList().get(0).getTestName(), "lol");
    assertEquals(tDao.getList().get(0).getPassword(), "12345");

    assertEquals("success", forward.getName());
}
```

How can I implement *testAddClientFailed()*??? :

```
    @Test
public void testAddSomethingFailed() throws Exception {
    form.setTestName("lol");
    t.checkIfExists("lol");


    ActionForward forward = action.addSomething(mapping, form, request, response);

    assertEquals("failure", forward.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock `tDao` and make `checkExistsTest` return false.

In your class which has the method

```
   public ActionForward addSomething(...)
```

You should inject (via the constructor) or set via a setter method an implentation of `TDao` which returns false for that method e.g.

```
FakeDao implements TDao {
 public boolean checkExistsTest(...) {return false;}
}
```

or subclass the concrete DAO and override this method.

You could also use a mocking framework to provide the implementation like [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/) or [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

Comment: Well I did what you told but I still can't to the test. I don't know why :s

Answer (score 0):

By implementing a DAO, either concrete or via a mock, that returns `false` for `checkExistsTest`, and check the forward name as you do now--what else is there?

This is one reason why dependency injection/inversion of control is so useful.

Without knowing anything for about how you're testing, how the DAO is instantiated/etc. it's difficult to provide concrete assistance. Ultimately (hopefully obviously) to test failure, you must failure.